# How to compare frequencies/sampling rates in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sample-data

is there a way to say that '13Min' is > '59S' and <'2H' using the frequency notation in pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [4]: from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

In [5]: to_offset('59s') < to_offset('1T')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: to_offset('13T') > to_offset('59s')
Out[6]: True

In [7]: to_offset('13T') < to_offset('59s')
Out[7]: False

In [8]: to_offset('13T') > to_offset('2H')
Out[8]: False

In [10]: to_offset('13T') < to_offset('2H')
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: This works until you start comparing e.g. month offsets:
to_offset('M') > to_offset('W') throws TypeError: unorderable types: MonthEnd() > Week()
Is there a way to compare these as well?

Comment: Comparing offsets alone can lead to undetermined results: example comparing 2M and 60D depends really on which month you pick. I would say that up to weeks things go pretty smooth, after that you need a start date to compare, relative to your exact case see answer by @igor-pozdeev above

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to add both frequencies to one common date and compare the resulting instances of `Timestamp`. This also addresses [**@rixmit**'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635721/how-to-compare-frequencies-sampling-rates-in-pandas/51134333#comment77929857_24635885).

```
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

In [4]: common_dt = pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01")
In [5]: f_a = common_dt + to_offset('59s')
In [6]: f_b = common_dt + to_offset('1T')
In [7]: f_a > f_b
Out[8]: False

In [9]: f_a = common_dt + to_offset('M')
In [9]: f_b = common_dt + to_offset('W')
In [10]: f_a > f_b
Out[10]: True
```

Comment: This solution seems not to be working wtih 'W' and 'D'.
common_dt = pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01")
f_a = common_dt + to_offset('D')
f_b = common_dt + to_offset('W')
f_a == f_b