# how to compare two grouper 'freq' windows

Tags: pandas

Function `foo` first summarizes values in given dataframe by `p1` and then by `p2`, where `p1` and `p2` are [`offset aliases`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Function
def foo(d, p1, p2, brk):
    # assert p2 > p1
    s1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p1)).sum().gt(brk)
    s2 = s1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p2)).sum()
    return s2

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.date_range("2017-01-01", "2017-03-31", freq="1H")})
np.random.seed(42)
df["val"] = np.random.sample(2137)
df = df.set_index("datetime")

foo(df, "7D", "1M", 80)
#             val
# datetime       
# 2017-01-31    4
# 2017-02-28    3
# 2017-03-31    3
```

The goal is to implement `assert p2 > p1` so that the result of `foo` is meaningful. One way would be to convert both `p1` and `p2` to `Timedelta` and compare them. However, some aliases such as `1M` aren't valid for conversion to `Timedelta`.

`pandas.Timedelta("1M")` gives following warning:

> FutureWarning: Units 'M', 'Y' and 'y' do not represent unambiguous
> timedelta values and will be removed in a future version

`pd.Grouper(freq="1M") > pd.Grouper(freq="7D")` gives following error:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'TimeGrouper' and
> 'TimeGrouper'

​What is the proper way to compare two grouper `freq` windows?

Comment: while the accepted answer does not work with 'M' and 'D' frequencies comparison, I would say this [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134333/9274732) is easy to implement in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51134333/17242583), you could probably do something like this:

```
def foo(d, p1, p2, brk):
    from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
    from datetime import datetime
    tmp = datetime.now()
    assert tmp + to_offset(p2) > tmp + to_offset(p1), 'p1 must be less than p2'
    
    s1 = d.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p1)).sum().gt(brk)
    s2 = s1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p2)).sum()
    return s2
```

Test:

```
>>> foo(df, "7D", "1M", 80)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [51], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 foo(df, "7D", "1M", 80)

Input In [50], in foo(d, p1, p2, brk)
      3 from datetime import datetime
      4 tmp = datetime.now()
----> 5 assert tmp + to_offset(p1) > tmp + to_offset(p2), 'p1 must be less than p2'
      7 s1 = d.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p1)).sum().gt(brk)
      8 s2 = s1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=p2)).sum()

AssertionError: p1 must be less than p2
```